# socket.io don't send data

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making a chat, with user list.

I order to send user list on each user connexion i do the following action from the server :

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var users = [];

    socket.on('user connexion', function (username) {

        if (typeof users[socket.handshake.address] == "undefined" ) {
            users[socket.handshake.address] = [];
        }

        users[socket.handshake.address].push({username : username, color: "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)});

        console.log(users);

        io.emit('user connexion',  {userlist : users});

    });

}
```

and in the front-end script i do :

```js
socket.on('user connexion', function(userList){

    console.log(userList);
});
```

But the console display :

```
Object {userlist: Array[0]}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `socket.handshake.address` a numeric value?

I think you wanted `users` to be an Object and make a hash-map out of it by adding as `socket.handshake.address` property your data (`{username : username, color: "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)}`).

Comment: That was that, i used `socket.handshake.address` as key for associative array, but it obviously didn't worked. So i set this as a property of the data : `users.push({ip: socket.handshake.address, username : username, color: "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)});`.